# how to run multiple comands or function together in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to return or execute multiple function in python at same time.

When I tried this it returned only one table.

I want every table as return.

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval

username = 'YourTradingViewUsername'
password = 'YourTradingViewPassword'

tv = TvDatafeed(username, password)

# index
nifty_index_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='NIFTY',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1000)

# futures continuous contract
nifty_futures_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='NIFTY',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1000,fut_contract=1)

# crudeoil
crudeoil_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='CRUDEOIL',exchange='MCX',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=5000,fut_contract=1)

# downloading data for extended market hours
extended_price_data = tv.get_hist(symbol="EICHERMOT",exchange="NSE",interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=500, extended_session=False)

nifty_index_data 

nifty_futures_data

extended_price_data
```

[I tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCiRR.png)

Comment: What, exactly, is your *specific* question?

Comment: when entered last comand  nifty_index_data or nifty_futures_data  or extended_price_data it return only one table  but i want all tables

Comment: Change the last 3 lines of your code to `print(nifty_index_data)`, `print(nifty_futures_data)`, and `print(extended_price_data)`.